# HTML Table Question

Tags: html, html-table

When you create a basic HTML table everything seems to stay in center of the table. I don't want this how can i stop this from happening?

I wish to use a 2 column html table one for column for a sidebar one for content. Because i have so much content the sidebar text (which is little) gos to the middle of column.

How do i align the text to stay to the top left of the columns?

Comment: This should interest you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/83073/why-not-use-tables-for-layout-in-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `<td>` element that contains the lefthand sidebar, try specifying a style that aligns text to the top:

`<td style="vertical-align: top">(Sidebar HTML code here)</td>`

Answer (score 1):

You can control the alignment of columns directly in your markup by using:

```
<td style="text-align: left; vertical-align: top;"></td>
```

or even just

```
<td align="left"></td>
```

This will work fine for a 2-column table, but Piccolomomo has the better plan if you are going to use it a lot.  This might help you further if you need it:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to change text aligning inside your table:

```
td {
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For aligning text in table you have to use css.Without css or any style sheet you can't make them align.So you can use inline css or external css for that.

```
<style type="text/css">
table td{
text-align:left;
vertical-align:top;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table>
     <tr valign="top">
        <td align="left">
           Side Bar
        </td>
        <td>
           Content
        </td>
     </tr>
</table>
```